# Retrieve desktop folders from iCloud drive

Tags: macos, icloud, desktop

I have a macbook pro with Monterey  OS, I stored my desktop files on iCloud drive, I logged out from iCloud in macbook, all desktop files are disappeared unless those that are not uploaded yet to iCloud because my iCloud is filled, when I trying to login again to my iCloud and to retrieve my desktop files I get this error:
`Your Documents and Desktop folders cannot be stored on iCloud Drive`
So how can I retrieve my desktop folders from filled iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

You can get to files stored in iCloud from the web to download them.

- https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/

If they never made it to the cloud, you need to use Time Machine or another backup solution to restore your missing files.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209174

Comment: I already checking my iCloud drive not sync all files, How can retrieve all data which were on desktop folder?

Comment: Oh, let me edit it the answer for checking your backup.

Comment: When I trying to check time machine, I didn't get a time machine that I can restore data.